# How to map resource/action permissions into claims

Tags: oauth, authorization, claims-based-identity, claims

There is an application which manages queues. Queues can be created dynamically and then someone can peek from queue, put into, clear queue or even delete it.

Application has it's own users and permissions, but now we're facing problem integrating different applications and we decided to move authentication to external identity provider.

So, now, with any queue operation request, application receives token, which "describes" who is the caller, claims of the caller. But the question is what to put into the user claims? Say "Queue3" was created and I want to give Bob right to peek from and put into *this* and only this queue. Authorization logic will be based on claims of Bob, but I have no better idea than construct such ugly claims named "Queue3_Peek_Put" and add it to Bob's claims. I can use two different claims ("Queue3_Peek" and "Queue3_Put"), but I'm afraid of token size bloating.

Anyway it seems very ugly for me. All I heard before about Claims-Based Authorization is that based on claims of the principal (name, age, eyes color, DoB, roles, organization etc) you can write your authorization logic, for example:

bool Allow(principalClaims, resource, requestedAction)

Where am I wrong? Are there any other ways to solve my problem?